# Formulation of two parameter Pareto distribution

Tags: distributions, simulation, density-function, pareto-distribution

So everywhere I've looked, I have seen the two parameter Pareto distribution formulated as
$\frac{\alpha\lambda^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}$. The distribution we are using in our course is $\frac{\alpha\lambda^\alpha}{(\lambda+x)^{\alpha+1}}$. I am required to simulate values in R for this, and R documentation shows it also uses the former formulation. Firstly I am confused as to how the formulation we are using is not to be found anywhere in my search, secondly, how can I simulate values for it in R?

Comment: Welcome to CV. These apparently are intended to be densities, but neither is correct: it is *essential* also to specify the support of the density.  Once you do that, the relationship between the two formulations will be apparent and easy to demonstrate using simple algebra.  I am confident your second question about simulating values is answered already here on CV: [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pareto+random+generate).

Comment: Thank you. I did consider the support but for some reason decided it must be the same in both cases. It is not. in the second case it is $x>0$, in the former it is $x>\lambda$. That should mean identical densities, and therefore identical simulation I think?

Comment: Right -- but they are identical densities *after accounting for the shift in location.*  It's just two very closely related ways of representing the same numbers: the first represents them as values while the second represents them as values *relative to an origin at $\lambda.$*  It's exactly like measuring temperatures in degrees Kelvin or Celsius, respectively.